# ggplot theme(): why doesn't changing line color do anything?

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I think I must be misunderstanding something about the `line =` argument in `theme()`. According to the documentation in `?theme`, `line =` is supposed to affect all line elements in the plot. However, changing the color doesn't do anything, while changing size does work.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() +
  theme(line = element_line(color = "green", size = 5))
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

My question is twofold:

1. Why doesn't changing the color affect any of the lines in the plot?
2. Why doesn't changing the size affect the line element from `geom_smooth()`?

EDIT: see @Gregor Thomas's answer for the answer to part 2.

Comment: The `line=` theme attribute is inherited only by `axis.line` properties, so I think you are only able to color the axes. I find it interesting that `line=` as shown here does not work, but if you use instead `theme(axis.line=element_text(...))`, the axes get the color you require. I suggest this may be a bug in `ggplot2` (that `line=` does not update the axis lines, whereas `axis.line` inherits from `line=` yet works).

Comment: @r2evans Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but the documentation says that all line attributes inherit from line, not the other way around. In theory it should apply the color to any kind of line, including axis or panel grid lines. The mystery is why it works for size but not color. Interestingly, the same exact situation happens for `theme(text = element_text(color = "green", size = 5))`: despite that axis.text should inherit from `text =`, only title text was affected by color, both title and axis text was affected by size. I think you're probably right that there is a bug here somewhere.

Comment: I agree. However, the only `*line*` theme attributes are for `axis.line*`, perhaps they have intentions for using it for other lines later? Or perhaps I'm misunderstand. But if you look through all of the available theme attributes, the only ones that include `line` are `axis.line`, which suggests that `line` and `axis.line` _should_ be the same. But they are not. Ergo, my thought that there might be a bug. Regardless of that bug, I believe that geometry lines (e.g., `geom_smooth`, `geom_line`) will _not_ inherit from it. Perhaps I'm misinterpreting `?theme`.

Comment: Looking at the documentation under each attribute individually, it looks like axis.ticks*, panel.grid*, and axis.line* should all inherit from line. Not a huge deal but did make me wonder whether I knew what I was talking about in front of my students today lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elements *do* inherit as advertised, however, they might have parents in between child `panel.grid.major.x` and grandparent `line`. This is for example the case for the `theme_gray()`, which is the default. To test this, you can manually set all theme elements with 'empty' elements. Like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_theme <- theme_get() # Default theme gray
my_theme[] <- lapply(my_theme, function(elem) {
  switch(
    class(elem)[[1]],
    "element_text" = element_text(),
    "element_line" = element_line(),
    "element_rect" = element_rect(),
    elem
  )
})
```

So with all steps between child and grandparent eliminated, all inherits as it should.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() +
  my_theme +
  theme(
    line = element_line(colour = "green"),
    axis.line = element_line() # was `element_blank()` by default
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Wow, while I understand what you're saying, to me that version of inheritance is inconsistent. Perhaps I'm looking at it too differently: if I say I want a grandparent `line=` to be the default for all lines, that says that inheriting attributes will ignore it if they already have that property set. Is there a lot of utility in inheritance-only-when-empty?

Comment: Got a response on GitHub that is very consistent with this answer. One of the maintainers actually posted a link to a helpful video which talks about this issue at around 15 minutes in. Definitely helped me understand this a little better. https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4947

Comment: @r2evans There is some utility to this method of inheritance. If you set the top `text = element_text()`, it doesn't change the angle of `axis.title.y.right` for example (which is awkwardly positioned in the plot above because it is empty). But yeah it makes the default themes a bit clunky to inherit with, I'd agree to that.

Answer (score 1):

In ggplot, `theme` is the way to customize **non-data** parts of a plot. This is why `theme()` has no effect on your `geom_smooth`, geoms are based on data. From the `?theme` help page:

> Themes are a powerful way to customize the non-data components of your plots: i.e. titles, labels, fonts, background, gridlines, and legends.

If you want to change a data component of the plot, put the customization directly in the layer you want to modify:

```
geom_smooth(color = "green", size = 5)
```

As for why your `theme(line = element_line(color = "green", size = 5))` doesn't change the color of any lines in the plot, it sets a default color for lines, which can be overriden. It seems like the default `theme_grey()` overrides the default line color for every type of specific line (major and minor panel grid lines which are the axis lines, axis tick lines, etc.), though some of the sizes must use the default or are set relative to the default, which is why the panel grid lines get huge with your `size = 5`.

Comment: I'd think that `theme(line=..)` would only ever be overridden when there is a call to `theme()` or `theme_*()` _after_ this was set, otherwise `theme(line=..)` should set the default for all (axis) lines. (Even `ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,disp)) + geom_path() + theme_gray() + theme(line=element_line(colour="green"))` does not work, explicitly placing the green part after the default theme. \*shrug\*)

Comment: Hmm, I haven't done a whole lot of theme customization, but my assumption is that if the theme specifies, say, `axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = "chartreuse")` then that specificity will override the preferences set at higher order theme elements like `axis.ticks` or `line`. Which is why the relative sizing still works--`theme_gray` defines `panel.grid = element_line(colour = "white")`, which overrides "green", and also `panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = rel(0.5))`, which is why the major grid line have size 5 and the minors have size 2.5 in OP's code.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, I think it's the inheritance working as intended.

Comment: My interpretation of inheritance is reversed from yours: I interpret it to mean that when you set (say) `axis.line=..`, then all of `axis.line.x` and `axis.line.y` and so on all inherit the explicit values to `axis.line=`. (This is demonstrated when using the OP's code and `theme(axis.line=)`, as both axes inherit the one setting.)

Comment: I suppose that makes more sense, luckily we have teunbrand to find the true culprit :)